# Diferença no número de disparos de eventos entre Android e iOS no Facebook SDK

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-sdk

Estou com o Facebook SDK 7.0.0 instalado em meu aplicativo React Native 0.62.2 e apesar de estar executando de forma igual, no events manager do Facebook, não aparecem os disparos de Android para determinados eventos padrões (`add_to_cart`, `add_to_wishlist`), apenas de iOS.
E mesmo assim existe uma discrepância no número das lojas.

```
logAddToCart(){
  try {
    AppEventsLogger.logEvent('fb_mobile_add_to_cart', 0, {
      PARAM_CONTENT_FACEBOOK: null,
      PARAM_CONTENT_ID_FACEBOOK: 0,
      PARAM_CONTENT_TYPE_FACEBOOK: null,
      PARAM_CURRENCY_FACEBOOK: null
    });
  } catch (err){
    console.log('Erro to add to cart:', err);
  }
}
```